# Distribution provisioning profile shown invalid in developer member center

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have got two apps in app store and two are active. Suddenly I found that one of my app's provisioning profile is shown "invalid" in member center. Other is with status "Active". Why is it so?

I am adding two points here

1. APNS with the now "invalid" provisioning profile was not working so I revoke the SSL certificate and its working well now. It was "Active" there after as well. Today morning it started showing "invalid".

   2.My account is going to expire on this weekend. would this be one of the cause? if so, why the other one is active.

Comment: I just gone through the app docs and found out the below link.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH30-SW28

which says something similar. My question is if I will go to edit---> and generate, then all apps which have currently provisioned will be of no use..cause I have to rebuild the app and submit to app store.

Comment: if I will recreate the provisioning profile and download that to my code(device), and then resubmit, will this have any effect on the already submitted app?

will there be any difference between old provisioned app and newly made app with new provisioning profile?